# Bluemix Node.js Watson Relationship Extraction using watson-developer-cloud module

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

The module seems broken, trying with the eimplest of tests results in an error.

My code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    http = require('http'),
    util = require('util'),
    bluemix = require('./config/bluemix'),
    watson = require('watson-developer-cloud'),
    extend = require('util')._extend;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views'); 

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var credentials = extend({
  version: 'v1',
  username: '<username>',
  password: '<password>'
}, bluemix.getServiceCreds('relationship_extraction')); // VCAP_SERVICES


var watson_relation = watson.relationship_extraction({
      username: credentials.username,
      password: credentials.password,
      version: 'v1'
});


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});


app.get('/extract', function(req, res){
    //var qtext = req.query['qtext'];
    //console.log('qtext=' + qtext);

    watson_relation.extract({
        text: 'IBM Watson developer cloud',
        dataset: 'ie-en-news' },
        function (err, response) {
            if (err)
                console.log('error:', err);
            else
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
    });

});

var server = require('http').createServer(app);

server.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port);
    console.log('To view the example, point your favorite browser to: localhost:3000');
});
```

Results in this in the log:

> error: [Error: Malformed results]

The older REST API version of this service seems to be working fine, just this version using the watson-developer-cloud module.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The Relationship Extraction service changed the response format and the wrapper can't parse the new one. I've created an issue (https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/nodejs-wrapper/issues/20) and will be working on that. I'll let you know once the npm module is updated.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you! I don't mind using the REST version in the meantime...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the [issue](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/nodejs-wrapper/issues/20). The service now accepts a `format` that can be `xml` or `json`(by default)
In order to test the service you can do:

```
var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud');

var relationship_extraction = watson.relationship_extraction({
  username: 'INSERT YOUR USERNAME FOR THE SERVICE HERE',
  password: 'INSERT YOUR PASSWORD FOR THE SERVICE HERE',
  version: 'v1'
});

relationship_extraction.extract({
  text: 'IBM Watson developer cloud',
  dataset: 'ie-en-news' },
  function (err, response) {
    if (err)
      console.log('error:', err);
    else
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
});
```